# Bootstrap button changes applied to all table rows

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs

I have a foreach loop that displays data into a table with a check-in button on each. Everytime I click the button, it changes them all? Any way to stop this without removing the foreach loops?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item._Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventId)</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-class="change()" ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>


                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAttendee", new {id = item.Id}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.Id})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }


$scope.change = function() {
                if($scope.toggleText == "Checked-in"){
                    return "btn btn-success btn-sm";
                }
                else{
                    return "btn btn-danger btn-sm";
                }
            };
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Is below button actual your check in button? Have you pass in the rowID you want to change to your change() method <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-class="change()" ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>

Comment: Improve your question with add `change()` function to the question

Comment: key to your problem is in change function , whatever it is doing it applies to every item , Answer of @Maher might help you here

Comment: I have added the change function. :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actully the `change()` already bind on `ng-class` and **this mean** it **run** when your page is run.

And `ng-click` have a `toggle` param, **this mean** all items in your `foreach` has same button, you have to change it to `item.toggle = !item.toggle`.

The `item.toggle` hint to that `item` which has `toggle` param, so when you click at that button you just change it not all of them.

**change()**

It's wrong way to use a function on `ng-class` directly, you can change it too, `ng-class="item.toggle ? 'btn-primary':'btn-danger'"` this is much better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your answer with no luck, it still changes all the buttons. `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-class="item.toggle ? 'btn-primary':'btn-danger'" ng-click="item.toggle = !item.toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>`

Comment: That because you didn't have item, actually you use item in c# mode not angularjs, and my question is why you don't try to get model data as json , it's more flexible with angular, with json you can use ng-repeat